# Not So Beginner Tutorial Request

Tags: c++, sdl

So my game is done for now but every time it flashes on the screen and my game loop is awful. So crowded with logic.

I need to learn more about games and how they are running. My idea now is that at the heart of the game you have a while loop. Inside that you are checking for events to happen. Each time an event happens, you spawn a thread that accomplishes a task.

You then have a layer that draws on the screen the "map". Also a layer that says where objects collide. And finally the logic of how objects interact.

I am using C++ and SDL and I need a complete tutorial that takes me through a complex example to get started. I am a good programmer but have no experience with games. Any suggested tutorials would help.

All tutorials I have found so far are too easy and don't do anything worth while.

Comment: if you are looking for a good SDL tutorial, you should take a look at [Lazyfoo's](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/index.php) but there are too many other great stuff out there. Check Other available tools before deciding to use SDL.

Comment: Tutorials being too easy indicates you don't need them. Make a game.

Comment: What would you use if not SDL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lazy Foo articles section was a great guide for me. Obviously his tutorials are top notch for sdl but these cover other things like game loops, state machines, ai etc.

http://lazyfoo.net/articles/index.php

My game loops are just an extension of his ideas in the game loop article and its served me well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a very good game programmer but I'll try to help you.

I suggest a very good book on game engine concepts called "[Game Engine Architecture](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568814135)". You should definitelly read it.

And one more thing: dive into the code of open-source games like Supertux and Kobo Deluxe. Both have very good performance and well organized code.

Hope it helps! =)